# Always “I have no answer for that” response in program ab when run from custom class

Tags: java, aiml

I'm trying to create custom chatbot using program ab. below is the class i've created

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String botname="super";
        String path="F:/Jars/NLP"; 
        Bot bot = new Bot(botname, path);
        Chat chatSession = new Chat(bot);
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

        String request = "Hello";
        do{
        request = sc.next();
        String response = chatSession.multisentenceRespond(request); 
        System.out.println(response); 
        }while(!request.equals("exit"));

    }}
```

When i run this class, I get following output

```
Name = super Path = F:/Jars/NLP/bots/super
c:/ab
F:/Jars/NLP/bots
F:/Jars/NLP/bots/super
F:/Jars/NLP/bots/super/aiml
F:/Jars/NLP/bots/super/aimlif
F:/Jars/NLP/bots/super/config
F:/Jars/NLP/bots/super/logs
F:/Jars/NLP/bots/super/sets
F:/Jars/NLP/bots/super/maps
Preprocessor: 0 norms 0 persons 0 person2
Get Properties: F:/Jars/NLP/bots/super/config/properties.txt
Loading AIML Sets files from F:/Jars/NLP/bots/super/sets
Loading AIML Map files from F:/Jars/NLP/bots/super/maps
AIML modified Thu Jun 15 19:03:38 IST 2017 AIMLIF modified Thu Jun 15 19:32:05 I
ST 2017
No deleted.aiml.csv file found
No deleted.aiml.csv file found
Loading AIML files from F:/Jars/NLP/bots/super/aimlif
Reading Learnf file
Loaded 2 categories in 0.015 sec
--> Bot super 2 completed 0 deleted 0 unfinished
Setting predicate topic to unknown
I like Mango
normalized = I
No match.
writeCertainIFCaegories learnf.aiml size= 0
I have no answer for that.
normalized = like
No match.
writeCertainIFCaegories learnf.aiml size= 0
I have no answer for that.
normalized = Mango
No match.
writeCertainIFCaegories learnf.aiml size= 0
I have no answer for that.
```

my AIML file
star.aiml

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<aiml>

   <category>
      <pattern>I LIKE *</pattern>
      <template>
         I too like <star/>.
      </template>
   </category>

   <category>
      <pattern>A * IS A *</pattern>
      <template>
         How <star index = "1"/> can not be a <star index = "2"/>?
      </template>
   </category>

</aiml>
```

.csv file

star.aiml.csv

```
0,I LIKE *,*,*,I too like <star/>.,star.aiml
0,A * IS A *,*,*,How <star index = "1"/> can not be a <star index = "2"/>?,star.aiml
```

when i run the Main class like below it works but when i run custom class it doesn't.

```
java -cp lib/Ab.jar Main bot=super action=chat trace=false
```

Can anybody please let me know what is wrong with custom class

Comment: You're asking what's wrong with the code you haven't shown us?

Comment: I've given all the files i created. Custom class also given.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the answer.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.alicebot.ab.AB;
import org.alicebot.ab.Bot;
import org.alicebot.ab.Chat;
import org.alicebot.ab.PCAIMLProcessorExtension;
import org.alicebot.ab.utils.IOUtils;


public class Test_001 {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String botname="super";
        String path="F:/Jars/NLP"; 
        org.alicebot.ab.AIMLProcessor.extension = new PCAIMLProcessorExtension();
        Bot bot = new Bot(botname, path,"chat");
        Chat chatSession = new Chat(bot);
        AB.ab(bot);
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

        String request = "Hello";
        do{

        request = IOUtils.readInputTextLine();
        String response = chatSession.multisentenceRespond(request); 
        System.out.println(response); 
        }while(!request.equals("exit"));

    }
}
```